# C# Finding the index of a specific iteration of a char

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a program that will loop through every character in a string and state that characters specific index

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter");
            string expression = Console.ReadLine();

            foreach(char c in expression)
            {
                if (c == '+')
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("plus detected! :{0}",expression.IndexOf(c));
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is that it doesn't say the index of the specific '+' it's up to in the loop, but instead states the first instance of the '+'

How can this be fixed to instead say the specific index

(eg. 1+2+3+4+5 should yield "1,3,5,7", the indexes(?) of each '+')

Comment: If you need the index, simply don't use `foreach`. Use a normal `for` loop, then you _got_ an index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a for loop as suggested by [@Ali Ezzat Odeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474594/c-sharp-finding-the-index-of-a-specific-iteration-of-a-char/49474642#49474642). Another solution would be using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, expression.Length)
                        .Where(index => expression[index] == '+');

foreach(var index in indices)
     Console.WriteLine(index);
```

Comment: Oh, that is clever.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < expression.Length; i++){
  if(expression[i]== '+'){
     Console.WriteLine("plus detected! :{0}",i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after reading this it makes sense, I tend to struggle visualizing ^_^;

Comment: the simplest way +1

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop to iterate the expression:

```
for(int i = 0; i < expression.length; i++) 
{
    if (expression[i] == '+')
    {
        Console.WriteLine("plus detected! :{0}", i);
    }
}
```

Or you introduce a custom counter

```
int i = 0;

foreach(char c in expression)
{
    if (c == '+')
    {
         Console.WriteLine("plus detected! :{0}", i);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: start `i` from 0

Comment: Ah this is also useful as I was still curious about if it was possible with a `foreach` loop :) thanks!

Comment: A `foreach` is basically just an automated `for` loop where you get objects and don't need to deal with indices yourself. Using a `foreach` and then keeping a manually incremented index defeats the purpose of using `foreach`, and is definite code smell.

Comment: Thanks for clarification ;)
It was still the way with least refactoring and i pointed out the possibility of a for loop.
Aominès approach is definitely the most elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This slight modification will solve your problem, whlie preserving your original code:

```
//you could even use byte for this to save memory :)
int index = -1;
Console.WriteLine("enter");
string expression = Console.ReadLine();

foreach (char c in expression)
    if (c == '+')
        Console.WriteLine("plus detected! :{0}", (index = expression.IndexOf(c,index + 1)));

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: oh this is interesting! Thank you, i'll give this a try as well :D